# Old bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}' (bash version 3.2)

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I cant figure out what's wrong with this:

```
$ {echo 3; echo 4; echo 5;} | cat
```

I get this:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
```

I am on bash version 3.2.
On zsh version 5.8, seems to work fine. Why doesn't old bash like this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like syntactically, we need a space here:

```
  { echo 3; echo 4; echo 5;} | cat

~~ ^ ~~~
```